# can't see what is causing extra whitespace below the footer

Tags: css

[This page](http://batmin.insightcomdes.com.au/contact/) contains 2 Google maps.

When you scroll to the bottom of the page, there is whitespace underneath the footer that is not present on any other page.

Disabling the two Google maps prevents the whitespace from occurring.

Can you see how the 2 Google maps are adding whitespace below the footer?

Comment: Two scrolls look bad

Comment: Remove this `body, html {
    height: 100%;
}`

Comment: Yes, I agree. I inherited the site from the last developer.

Comment: removing height 100% seems to be fixing the scrolls too as @Anuresh suggested

Comment: @Anuresh, removing that line resolved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Steve glad that woeked :)

Comment: @Anuresh you can answer the question i guess :P

Comment: @MehravishTemkar We already solved the issue , no need to ans now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `height:100%` from body from **wtc.style.css**

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Simple one just remove `body {
     overflow-x: hidden;}